# How can I fix the origin No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource in Go API using the Gin Framework?

Tags: go, next.js, cors, go-gin

I'm trying to make an API call to my endpoint (http:localhost:8080/orders?page=10&pageSize=10) written in Go with the Gin framework. My frontend is a Nextjs app. I'm getting "origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource".

I've already tried using https://github.com/gin-contrib/cors and https://github.com/rs/cors. I also tried to do it setting the headers manually but I can't seem to make it work.

Right now my code is looking like this:

```golang
func Init(init *configs.Initialization) *gin.Engine {

    router := gin.New()
    router.Use(cors.Default())
    router.Use(gin.Logger())
    router.Use(gin.Recovery())

    orders := router.Group("/orders")
    {
        orders.GET("/", init.OrderController.GetOrders)

        orders.GET("/:orderID", init.OrderController.GetOrder)
    }

    return router
}
```

With cors being imported from "github.com/gin-contrib/cors".

Any help is appreciated, I've tried every answer that I've found but no luck yet.

Comment: can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I'm not sure why `core.Default()` is not working in the code you showed. 
How about the order of lines? like this https://go.dev/play/p/GZtaTlgbVhl

Comment: Or please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54665442/cors-doesnt-work-on-gin-and-golang-group-routes

Comment: What does your client code look like?

Comment: In my client code I'm doing a simple fetch with Axios:

axiosExplorerApi.get(`/orders?page=${options.pageIndex}&pageSize=${options.pageSize}`);

Comment: @NICOLASFRANCORAMPOLDI Add the relevant client code (it should show show how `axiosExplorerApi` is configured) and server code in your question; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Also, please share the full CORS error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things take into account that may help you solve your issue:

1. CORS wont be a problem when dealing with [Simple Requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests)

   ***TLDR***

   Simple requests in Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) are requests that do not trigger preflight checks. They must meet the following criteria:

   1. HTTP Methods: Limited to GET, HEAD, or POST.
   2. Content-Type: The Content-Type header must be one of the following:

   - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
   - multipart/form-data
   - text/plain

   3. Custom Headers: Only simple request headers are allowed. These include:

   - Accept
   - Accept-Language
   - Content-Language

- If you are simply making a `GET` request without any custom/aditional headers CORS should not be a problem.

2. Make sure to test the scenario in *Incognito Mode* or disabling cache in the network tab.

- Your CORS preflight request may be cached, preventing changes in the configuration to get applied.

3. Make sure the following cors options are set correctly:

   - Access-Control-Allow-Origin: This header indicates which origins are allowed to access the resource. It can be set to a specific origin, "*", or a list of allowed origins.
   - Access-Control-Allow-Methods: Specifies the methods (HTTP verbs) that are allowed when accessing the resource. For example, "GET", "POST", "PUT", etc.
   - Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Indicates which headers can be used during the actual request. This header is used in response to a preflight request.
   - Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: Specifies whether the response to the request can be exposed when the credentials flag is true. This allows for sending credentials (such as cookies or authorization headers) with the request.
   - Access-Control-Max-Age: Specifies how long the results of a preflight request (the information contained in the Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Allow-Headers headers) can be cached.
   - Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Indicates which headers can be exposed as part of the response by listing their names.
   - Access-Control-Request-Method: Used when issuing a preflight request to indicate the method (such as GET, POST, etc.) that will be used in the actual request.
   - Access-Control-Request-Headers: Used when issuing a preflight request to indicate which headers will be sent with the actual request.

- For example, If you are paginating your response using the *link* headers you should take into account *Access-Control-Expose-Headers*

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, it was super helpful! In this case the error was that the preflight request was being cached, I disabled cache in the network tab of the developer tools and it worked.